# Python xlwt how DO NOT overwrite the cell?

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

Storing some scraped data  with Python Selenium to excel file
but stuck at the moment of storing the data.
Here is a code example wich gives me "Attempt to overwrite the cell" exception
I don t want to overwrite the cells, just need to add data from next site page.

Can you help me?
I found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647138/python-attempt-to-overwrite-cell-error) but dont know how to apply it

```
i=0
while i<len(newPagesFile):
    url = "http://example.com"

    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)
    names = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('path1')
    places = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('path2')

        for j, (name, place) in enumerate(zip(names, places)):
            ws.write(i, 0, name.text)
            ws.write(i, 1, place.text)

        i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `i+=1` needs to be indented so it is inside the `for` loop. Otherwise, each iteration of the `for` loop tries to store the data in the same cell, leading to the error message you describe.

Comment: if   i+=1 indented, the upper loop is not working, but the data stores correctly - but only ones